# Limits of convergent/divergent sequences (revision): $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n] {100n+25+6^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

I need to find the limit :

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n] {100n+25+6^n}$$

I also got limit ${a^{1/n}} = 1$, ${n^{1/n}}= 1$ and $(1+1/n){^n} = e$

I haven't come across a question like this before so I'm stuck on how to tackle it. My first thoughts are to use the bernoulli inequality since the question I got afterwards is $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ $(1 + \frac{3}{n^2})^{n^2}$ and I obviously can't expand it fully or cancel it out easily.

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the result often called the [Squeeze Theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) For large enough $n$ (and it doesn't have to be very large!), we have $100n+25+6^n<2\cdot 6^n$ and therefore
$$6 <\sqrt[n]{100n+25+6^n}<2^{1/n}(6).$$
Now let $n \to\infty$. As you mentioned, $2^{1/n}\to 1$.

Comment: Bleh, I should have seen this; I always try sledgehammers first :) (+1 btw.)

Comment: @David Mitra: A sledgehammer is a very good tool.

Comment: whats a sledgehammer? Could you also explain the answer a bit more I don't fully understand how you got there

Comment: How did you use the squeeze theorem in your example?

Comment: also would i use the squeeze theorem again for the second question i mentioned above?

Comment: What second question? To finish the proof by Squeeze Theorem, the left stays at $6$, the part $2^{1/n}(6)$ approaches $6$, and so the term in between, which is what we are interested in, approaches $6$ (look at reference given).

Answer (score 2):

One way:

Use the fact that for positive $a_n$, if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} {a_{n+1}\over a_n}$ exists, then so does   $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \root n\of{a_n}$ and in this case the two limits are equal (see the last page [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130728110356/http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/243series4.pdf) for a proof of this fact).

For your sequence
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} {100(n+1)+25+6^{n + 1}\over100n+25+6^{n } }
$$
is relatively easy to compute (by dividing each term by $6^n$, for example).

Another way:

First calculate  $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ln\root n\of {100n+25+6^n}
=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\ln ( {100n+25+6^n})\over n}$ using L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Using $\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{{a_n}}$ is definitely not a sledgehammer.

Comment: I don't know what L'hopitals rule is so I don't think I can use that. but the first method seems pretty solid. I'm gonna check that out

Comment: @Jeremy I think you should use Andre's approach.

Comment: The notes linked in the answer are now part of Pete L. Clark's text [Honors Calculus](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20220503044808/http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf)). (Sorry for several pings - this is related to cleanup after [the recent bulk replacement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34750). I'd guess [your posts with the dead links from this domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a18986%20url%3apete%2f243) have already been edited.)